# How can i optimize my code in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code. How can I refactor this to easily put them in a JavaScript array?
This is some of the pic containers that I would like to put in the array.

```
Ace = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("Ace"));
aceContainer = new createjs.Container();
aceContainer.addChild(Ace);
aceContainer.x = 90;
aceContainer.y = 148;
aceContainer.width = 276 ;
aceContainer.height = 266;
stage.addChild(aceContainer);

K = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("K"));
kContainer = new createjs.Container();
kContainer.addChild(K);
kContainer.x = 376;
kContainer.y = 148;
kContainer.width = 276 ;
kContainer.height = 266;
stage.addChild(kContainer);

Q = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("Q"));
qContainer = new createjs.Container();
qContainer.addChild(Q);
qContainer.x = 662;
qContainer.y = 148;
qContainer.width = 276 ;
qContainer.height = 266;
stage.addChild(qContainer);
```

Comment: ```var array = [ ]; array.push(Ace); array.push(K); array.push(Q);``` ?

Comment: a function that use the array to get x , y ,width , height

Comment: aha. Misunderstood completely then =)

Comment: anthony - there is no array - perhaps define the array you speak of to get the answer you require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
function doThingsPeter(s, x, y, width, height, root) {
    var bm = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult(s));
    var container = new createjs.Container();
    container.addChild(bm);
    container.x = x;
    container.y = y;
    container.width = width;
    container.height = height;
    root.addChild(container);
    return container;
}
var containers = [];
containers.push(doThingsPeter('Ace', 90, 148, 276, 266, stage));
containers.push(doThingsPeter('K', 376, 148, 276, 266, stage));
containers.push(doThingsPeter('Q', 662, 148, 276, 266, stage));
```

maybe?
edit: in response to "what about containers naming" - I can only guess you may want something like

```
function doThingsPeter(s, x, y, width, height, root) {
    var bm = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult(s));
    var container = new createjs.Container();
    container.addChild(bm);
    container.x = x;
    container.y = y;
    container.width = width;
    container.height = height;
    root.addChild(container);
    return container;
}
var containers = {};
containers.Ace = doThingsPeter('Ace', 90, 148, 276, 266, stage);
containers.K = doThingsPeter('K', 376, 148, 276, 266, stage);
containers.Q = doThingsPeter('Q', 662, 148, 276, 266, stage);
```

but that's not an Array now

Or did you want something like:

```
var containers = {};
var bitmaps = {};
var arrayOfThings = [
    { target: 'Ace', x: 90, y: 148, width: 276, height: 266},
    { target: 'K', x: 376, y: 148, width: 276, height: 266},
    { target: 'Q', x: 662, y: 148, width: 276, height: 266}
];
arrayOfThings.forEach(function(thing) {
    var target = thing.target;
    var bm = bitmaps[target] = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult(target));
    var container = containers[target] = new createjs.Container();
    container.addChild(bm);
    container.x = thing.x;
    container.y = thing.y;
    container.width = thing.width;
    container.height = thing.height;
    stage.addChild(container);
});
```

as a result:

- containers.Ace would contain the `Ace` container
- bitmaps.Ace would contain the `Ace` bitmap

etc

fourth and FINAL attempt (based on comments again)

```
function doThingsPeter(s, x, y, width, height, root) {
    var bm = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult(s));
    var container = new createjs.Container();
    container.addChild(bm);
    container.x = x;
    container.y = y;
    container.width = width;
    container.height = height;
    root.addChild(container);
    return container;
}

aceContainer = doThingsPeter('Ace', 90, 148, 276, 266, stage);
kContainer = doThingsPeter('K', 376, 148, 276, 266, stage);
qContainer = doThingsPeter('Q', 662, 148, 276, 266, stage);
```

Now you have the aceContainer, kContainer and qContainer as per your question

Comment: what about containers naming ?

Comment: look in my original code every container have a name identifing him bcz i want to use that id later on in my programe . can i use the string id before the container to give him an id?

Comment: @anthony - added another possibility

Comment: @anthony - in the second version, instead of container.Ace = ... container.K = ... and container.Q = ... just use aceContainer = ... kContater = ... qContainer = ... - but you wont have Ace, K or Q variables -

Comment: in this case all the pictures are added to one container called conatainer but also i am trying to call this container i get an error Uncaught ReferenceError: Container is not defined, i want to put every pic in a container like i did in my original code : aceContainer = new createjs.Container();
aceContainer.addChild(Ace); in the edited version that you gaved to me how can i select a container ?

Comment: in versions 2 and 3, containers.Ace ... containers.K ... containers.Q ... but I already told you how to change version 2 to something more like your question - you did ask for `optimize` - and having the containers contained in one object could make other optimizations possibe

Comment: you meen somthing like :   aceContainer = new createjs.Container();
aceContainer.addChild(container.Ace);

Comment: I've made a final addition - if that doesn't answer the question, I'll just delete the whole answer

Comment: your answer was very useful but i have one more question in the version 3   how can i select a container containing the ace or the q bitmap for example? thanks in advance .

Comment: please Jaromanda X can u answer my last question its a critical question for me thank you in advance

Comment: containers.Ace containers.K containers.Q .. exactly how it says after the code